# objectAtIndex not passing selected row in segue

Tags: arrays, uitableview, dictionary, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm hoping to pass data of a selected row to a second viewcontroller with segue. The results that fill the first viewcontroller tableview are an array. In the segue I'm using:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
    //
    DetailVC *dvc = (DetailVC *)[segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.resultsVC indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Car *selectedCar = (Car *) [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dvc.currentCar = selectedCar;
```

When I perform segue I get the error:

```
[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 carName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

From the research I've done on this topic I do include something similar to the line:

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType]
```

Which when deleted has helped others. I'll need to keep it for my code. 
How can I pass data of the selected row to the second viewcontroller?

**Update 8JULY**

The code i'm using to construct the array is from a fetchrequest. The array row currently displays an integer and carName.

```
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:&error];
NSSortDescriptor* sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:NO];

results = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
self.results = results;
```

Is the issue that I'm pointing the segue to search Car* rather than this array output?

**Update 12JULY**

Following suggestions of Aubada Taljo I removed reference of Car* and add the following to the segue:

```
dvc.selectedCar = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and declared NSDictionary in my detailVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the problem is here, then are you sure self.results contain objects of type Car*?

I would suggest you check in the variables watcher that it contains objects of type Car* because it seems you are requesting the property carName from an object of another type.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'm stumbling though variable watcher for the first time, in results array i'm getting a list of numbers with (Class)NSKnownKeysDictionary1 after each. Is this correct? I've updated question with code for how array is built.

Comment: Your array contains Dictionary objects, while your code is trying to parse them to Car objects, in the new code you added, you should convert this Dictionaries array to Cars array like this e.g.
Car* car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.carName = dictionary[@"carName"]

of course you should put this code in a for loop to parse all the dictionaries and build the new array.

Comment: When I select print description on selectedCar I get - Printing description of selectedCar:
{
    carName = "Mustang ";
    objectID = "0xd00ac0002 <x-coredata://78C8BC79-F83C-432F-B6FD-42BA8CA866EC/Car/p43>";
    ranking = 2;
}

Comment: Will converting dictionaries effect these other properties and how the array fills the tableview? I'm only interested in passing carName to the next viewcontroller. Can that be converted as you suggest in the segue?

Comment: That might mean you have a key "carName" in the dictionary but doesn't mean you can access it directly, just try selectedCar[@"carName"];